# Minus blank Rows in between rows that contains specific text - Excel

Tags: excel, match, formula, subtraction

I  have an interesting problem.

I have made good progress but struggling on the following.
I am working with a log file that can be X amount of rows long.
In the log there are a millisecond time snap that was an action of processing files.

Now I'd like to know how many files were processed in that time frame.

What I have so far is the following and it works well:

``=MATCH("*INFO*", B:B, 0)-MATCH("*021DR*",B:B, 0)```

[image: My Excel]

Although my answer is five, I'd like to minus the empty rows between the two specific values. So my expected results need to be 1.

I have tried `=MATCH("*INFO*",H:H,0)-MATCH("*021DR*",H:H,0)-COUNTBLANK(H:H)` but that then counts all empty rows in my sheet. I need to - the empty rows between the matched value.

I cant have specific rows as this file is countless rows long, and the amount of files processed are also unknow. I am happy that it finds 5...

Any ideas ?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job. At least, my addition does count the blank rows between the 2 MATCH results.

```
=MATCH("*INFO*",H:H,0)-MATCH("*021DR*",H:H,0)-COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("*INFO*", B:B, 0), 2) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH("*021DR*", B:B, 0), 2)))
```

However, I think the following wouldn't be inferior.

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("*INFO*", B:B, 0), 2)&":"& ADDRESS(MATCH("*021DR*", B:B, 0), 2)))
```

The problem seems to be that the function returns 1 when nothing is matched. I guess it needs embedding in an IF function of some kind to weed out those results.